# Open display calibration screen programmatically

Tags: android

I have figured out that in order to calibrate accelerometer in Android I don't need to do anything special I just need to open the horizontal calibration screen in the GB and G-Sensor calibration screen in the iCS+ now how can I open these activities programmatically?

I am able to open the display settings but can't open calibration screen

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Comment: You may not want to do that since only my HTC phone has the setting for calibration. My Motorola and Nexus S do not have this option.

Comment: Really they don't have this option? so how do they calibrate the display

Comment: I do not know if calibrate would do anything. I just do the figure 8 myself. I haven't work on sensor for a while so I do not remember the calibration from the HTC helps or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Really they don't have this option?

I have ~50 Android devices and have not seen a calibration option on most of them. In fact, I cannot recall seeing a calibration option on a device manufactured since 2009. And there is nothing in [the AOSP Settings app](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings) that suggests to me that it is a calibration mechanism.

Certainly, there is no documented and supported means of starting such a Settings screen.

Comment: so there is no way I can calibrate the device's G-sensor?

Comment: @AashishBhatnagar: I have no idea what a "G-sensor" is with respect to Android, as `SensorManager` does not support one by that name. Regardless, few Android devices have any forms of calibration for anything -- touchscreen, camera, etc.